# How can I make CSS hover effect touch screen friendly in Angular applications?

Tags: css, angular, hover, touch, user-experience

I have a pop up sign-in box which is shown when a person hover over the particular icon. How can I make it touch screen friendly in the Angular application?

This is the logic from my component:

```
private isPopupDisplayed: boolean = false;

mouseOver(event) {
    this.isPopupDisplayed = true;
    // console.log(`mouseOver ${this.isPopupDisplayed}`);

}

mouseLeave(event) {
    this.isPopupDisplayed = false;
    // console.log(`mouseLeave ${this.isPopupDisplayed}`);
}
```

Comment: But in touch screen does not have hover, it's only click event (active).